# Facebook Registration "That 'redirect_uri' isn't allowed for that client_id."

Tags: facebook, redirect, registration

I'm trying to use the Facebook's Registration plugin and i keep getting this error: 
 "That 'redirect_uri' isn't allowed for that client_id."

My [settings in FB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMbQW.jpg):

[image]

Source: 
    `<div id="fb-reg">
         <fb:registration 
         fields="name,birthday,gender,location,email" 
         redirect-uri="http://www.facebook.com/develtestpage/signupsuccess.php"
         width="530">
         </fb:registration>
      </div>`

I found a few article but it should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `redirect uri` from `http://www.facebook.com/develtestpage/signupsuccess.php` to `http://cold-dawn-9801.herokuapp.com/`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your domain. ( App-domain )

Facebook will allow redirect only to the registered domain for the client id.

Comment: @Subir Kumar Sao: Can't I test it on my localhost? Any way to achieve the same?

Comment: @ChaZ . You cannot directly use it on localhost domain. You have the option of using Dyna Dns (http://dyn.com/dns/). If you also have a free webhosting and redirect the local host.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao: Thanks. Btw, am getting [this](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-l1xgJLuMGVs/Uo4ugP-lG9I/AAAAAAAAAnM/KZGyPHSzoqo/s1335/Untitled.png) strange error when trying to create an App on [Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com). Any means to solve the same?

Comment: @SubirKumarSao: Good news! FB plugins can be used on localhost as well, and it works really smooth. Here's the code snippet which I used:
    `<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
             client_id=644171685634840&
             fields=name&
             redirect_uri=http://localhost:8084/CEO-System/fbreg.php" width="950" height="320">
</iframe>`